# productsign mac .pkg installer

Tags: macos, sign, pkg-file, productsign

I need to sign a MacOS installer with .pkg extension. I have a .pfx certificate and added it to Keychain. It contains both certificate and the private key.

But when I try to sign this .pkg using `productsign` utility, it shows an error as :

> productsign --sign "commonName" unsigned.pkg signed.pkg
>
> productsign: error: Could not find appropriate signing identity for
>   “commonName”. An installer signing identity (not an application
>   signing identity) is required for signing flat-style products.

Answer (score 4):

These steps work for us:

1. Unlock the keychain:

   ```
   security unlock-keychain -p {keychain_password} /Users/{your_user}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
   ```
2. List the available signing identities:

   **Note:** Code signing identities cannot be used to sign a pkg in mac.  You can find these by adding `-p codesigning` to the below command.

   ```
   security find-identity -v
   ```
3. Sign an installer using productsign:

   **Note:** The identity can typically be the long hex code from the above command:

   ```
   productsign --sign "{your_identity}" original.pkg signed.pkg
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out what the name of your pfx is and replace the "commonName" with it.

U should search for something like "Developer ID Application: ..." to sign the package.